# Jquery slim scroll with jquery ui sortable issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-sortable

Hi I have a situation where I am using jquery **slim scroll plugin** with **jquery sortable**. The problem is when I drag the items from one list items to other the scroll bar on the right doesn't move along with , So if I have to drop the list to the last list items area I cannot go there unless I use **mousewheel**.
So how can i bind scrollbar position as I drag the item from one list area to other. Below is the code-

```js
$(function() {
   $("ul.droptrue").sortable({

     revert: 'invalid',
     connectWith: "ul"
   });


   $("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3").disableSelection();


   $('.ScrollableAreanew ').slimScroll({
     height: '400',
     width: '100%',
     alwaysVisible: true,
     color: 'rgb(15,170,255)',
     railOpacity: 1,
     opacity: 1,
     size: '5px',
     position: 'right',
     allowPageScroll: false,


   });
 });
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2,
#sortable3 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li,
#sortable3 li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://rocha.la/misc/jsdemos/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<div class="ScrollableAreanew">
  <ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Can be dropped..</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">..on an empty list</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="sortable2" class="droptrue">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Cannot be dropped..</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">..on an empty list</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="sortable3" class="droptrue">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Cannot be dropped..</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">..on an empty list</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yes you are right my mistake i was off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Here what we need to do is

1. Get position of mouse - Y coordinate as we move inside the `.ScrollableAreanew`
2. Whenever a sortable item is moved (use `sort` event), move the slimScroll to the scrolled position using `scrollTo`.

`sort` event is triggered during sorting. See [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-sort) for more details

```js
$(function() {
  var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
   $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
        currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
        currentMousePos.y = event.pageY; // Get position of mouse - Y coordinate
   });
  
  $("ul.droptrue").sortable({
     sort : function(event, ui) { // This event is triggered during sorting.
     var scrollTo_int = currentMousePos.y + 'px';
    $(".ScrollableAreanew").slimScroll({
     scrollTo : scrollTo_int, // scroll to mouse position
     height: '400',
     width: '100%',
     alwaysVisible: true,
     color: 'rgb(15,170,255)',
     railOpacity: 1,
     opacity: 1,
     size: '5px',
     position: 'right',
     allowPageScroll: false
  });
     },
     revert: 'invalid',
     connectWith: "ul"
   });

   $("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3").disableSelection();

   $('.ScrollableAreanew ').slimScroll({
     height: '400',
     width: '100%',
     alwaysVisible: true,
     color: 'rgb(15,170,255)',
     railOpacity: 1,
     opacity: 1,
     size: '5px',
     position: 'right',
     allowPageScroll: false
   });
 });
```

```css
#sortable1,
#sortable2,
#sortable3 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#sortable1 li,
#sortable2 li,
#sortable3 li {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.justAddingHeight
{
  height:100px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://rocha.la/misc/jsdemos/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<div class="justAddingHeight"></div>
<div class="ScrollableAreanew">
  <ul id="sortable1" class="droptrue droppable">
    <li class="ui-state-default draggable">Can be dropped..</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default draggable">..on an empty list</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default draggable">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default draggable">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default draggable">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="sortable2" class="droptrue droppable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">Cannot be dropped..</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">..on an empty list</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="sortable3" class="droptrue droppable">
    <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">Cannot be dropped..</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">..on an empty list</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-highlight draggable">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

1. Instead of getting mouse position inside the `.ScrollableAreanew` div, get the position of mouse in the `document`.

***Note:*** Added  div with class `justAddingHeight` (having height of `100px`) as a POC.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This solution dint worked for me as this calculates the mouse position according to window..  And  this structure of code  is placed at bottom of page above footer..  Which doesnot make it work as wanted..

Comment: @SahilDhir Updated my answer. Check if it is working now.

Comment: Please see the jerk it produce to slim scroll when a item is dragged from first ul.. I want the things to work smoothly as the mouse position solution within a particular area is not giving accurate results..

Comment: @SahilDhir: As I can see in the snippet, it is working smoothly according to the snippet you provided. Secondly, there may be an issue in integration in your code. Some CSS or JS may conflict with this snippet. That's why I provided with a minimal verifiable POC. As far as accuracy is concerned, the snippet I provided is accurate as per your question but it may not be accurate in your structure of code. You can edit your question and provide additional code to tell us more about the issue.

Comment: I am checking your code only and I am still trying to figure this out.I can see a displacement , try to drag first element and then see the scroll how it moves ..